# Recursive Replace of Files and Directory names while Preserving the Case

Tags: linux, ubuntu

In the shell, how can I do a recursive replace of filename and directory names in a directory's contents, while preserving the existing case? For example, a subdirectory could be named "Test" or "test" and I want to be able to replace it with "Testa" or "testa" respectively.

Comment: Don't think your question is very clear.

Comment: @Junaid, I just added an example.

Answer (score 0):

WORD OF CAUTION - Run this carefully as you might end up renaming a lot of files and then realise you added the wrong character to the files. There is no undo button here;)

Alright if I understood you correctly then this will do it.

The folder structure with a few .txt files is

```
C:\Folder\firstfolder
C:\Folder\fourthFolder
C:\Folder\SecondFolder
C:\Folder\Thirdfolder
C:\Folder\firstfolder\aFile.txt
C:\Folder\SecondFolder\Anotherfile.txt
C:\Folder\Thirdfolder\yetAnotherFile.txt
```

The script is as below. I had to separate folder and files as files have extensions and you probably don't want to add your rename string after the extension.

```
$source="C:\Folder"
$addtoname="A"

Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse | foreach {
    $location = Split-Path $_.FullName
    if($_.PSIsContainer){
        $name=$_.Name
        Rename-Item $location"\"$name $location"\"$name$addtoname
    }
    else
    {
        $name = $_.BaseName
        $ext = $_.Extension
        Rename-Item $location"\"$nameext  $location"\"$name$addtoname$ext
    }
}
```

And the results afterwards are

```
C:\Folder\firstfolderA
C:\Folder\fourthFolderA
C:\Folder\SecondFolderA
C:\Folder\ThirdfolderA
C:\Folder\firstfolderA\aFileA.txt
C:\Folder\SecondFolderA\AnotherfileA.txt
C:\Folder\ThirdfolderA\yetAnotherFileA.txt
```

I hope this is what you wanted and I did not invest my time in this for nothing.

Comment: thank you very much, but do you have a similar script for Linux?  I'm sure your script will help others with Windows.

Comment: Well I will try and write one for linux, sorry should have checked that before but powershell does run on linux now ;)